# What would the keyframe code look like the this animation?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am new to CSS3 animations, and an animation that I like [here](http://easings.net/#easeOutBounce). Unfortunately the animation exists in a jQuery easings library which would have a dependency on jQuery, which my current project does not.

How would I implement this animation using CSS3 keyframes to animate the width of a div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the extreme points in the values, and use those as keyframe. Also, pay attention to the different timing functions

```css
.test {
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  animation: grow 5s infinite;

}

@keyframes grow {
   0% {width: 100px; animation-timing-function: ease-in}  
  30% {width: 600px; animation-timing-function: ease-out}
  45% {width: 400px; animation-timing-function: ease-in}
  60% {width: 600px; animation-timing-function: ease-out}
  70% {width: 500px; animation-timing-function: ease-in}
  84% {width: 600px; animation-timing-function: ease-out}
  92% {width: 550px; animation-timing-function: ease-in}
 100% {width: 600px; animation-timing-function: ease-out}
 
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css would look like this:

```
.slide-width {
      animation: slide-width 3s linear 0s forwards;
      -webkit-animation: slide-width 3s linear 0s forwards;
}
```

and the keyframes would be something like this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slide-width {
    0% {width:50px}
    100% {width:100px}
}
@keyframes slide-width {
    0% {width:50px}
    100% {width:100px}
}
```